# How to fix z-index with a Modal and a sticky navbar in Vue.js?

Tags: css, vue.js, navbar, z-index

Thanks in advance for your help. 
I will update this post with the solution because I think some people can have the same issue and after some search on the web I found no answer.

**The problem**
I use a modal component in a component included in my App.vue. Everything works except with the navbar because when i put the mouse in the window, the navbar become white and go over the black background of the modal.

*You can see the front in the image below when the mouse is out.

// Unfortunatelly I need 10 reputations to add it.*

To fix that I tried lot of things but nothing works right now. If I delete z-index:1 from the navbar the problem is fixed but if i put some font awesome content on my website, the navbar will appear behind.

The css

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    height: 50px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.modal-mask {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 100;
}
.modal {
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

The App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <NavBar></NavBar>
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import NavBar from './components/layout/Navbar'
  export default {
    components: {
      NavBar
    },
  }
</script>
```

The modal

```
<template>
        <div class="modal-mask">
            <div class="modal"
                role="dialog">
                <slot name="body">
                    No content
                </slot>
            </div>
        </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: 'modal',
        methods: {
            close() {
                this.$emit('close');
            },
        },
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

z-index only works with position try to give position to .modal class relative or absolute

Comment: Unfortunatelly is not so easy. The problem with the black screen comes from modal-mask and I have a position fixed on it ;(